# json array Object reference Assignment make me confused

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
<script>
 var arr = [{"val":0},{"val":1},{"val":2},{"val":3},{"val":4},{"val":5}];
 var arrCopy = [];

 for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var tmp = arr[i];
  arrCopy.push(tmp);
 }
 for(var j=0; j < arrCopy.length; j++){
   arrCopy[j].val = arrCopy[j].val+1;

 }
  console.log("arr:", arr);        //resullt: [{"val",1},{"val",2},{"val",3},{"val",4},{"val",5},{"val",6}]
  console.log("arrCopy", arrCopy);//resullt: [{"val",1},{"val",2},{"val",3},{"val",4},{"val",5},{"val",6}]
</script>
```

1. **Why they print the same array?that's make me confused?**
2. arrCopy just get the arr's  reference ? not the value's copy?
3. When can I　get it's(arr) value copy not the reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is when you are saying

```
tmp = arr[i] // it's just a reference of {"val":0} to tmp not a copy.
```

better do this

```
var tmp = {};
tmp.val = arr[i].val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a small mistake in your syntax; instead of using a comma inside each of the `{"val",0}` maps, use a colon: `{"val":0}`. So change `arr` to

```
var arr = [{"val":0},{"val":1},{"val":2},{"val":3},{"val":4},{"val":5}];
```

By doing this, you're saying that there is a mapping from `"val"` to the number on the right of the colon.

Comment: yes!I edited again, I actually make a mistake, and this is my question now! Why they print the same array?